# ASP.NET MVC2 application splitted into several assemblies having views in each assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, plugins, assemblies, partial-views

I want to implement a base web application using ASP.NET MVC2 that will automatically scan the deployed assemblies for implementations of a certain interface - lets call it IWebModule. So it should be possible for third party vendors to implement the interface to integrate their module into the application. Of course there have to be two assemblies at the minimum - one for the base web application and one for the module.

To make things a bit more clear imagine that the base application has a preferences view that displays all available IWebModule implementations in a tree and by clicking on one of the nodes a module specific preferences view will be shown.

The third-party preference view, controller, and model should be implemented in the CustomeModuleSolution, not in the BaseApplicationSolution. This approach should also be useable for other things like application menus, toolbars etc.  The application functionality can be enhanced by just implementing provided interfaces of the base application - so this is like using extension points to add functionality to the application by implementing interfaces which register add-ins and event handlers for further use.

The focus of this question is the how to implement the model, views and controller in different solutions (or split an web application into module solutions) and how to get it run together.

```
CustomModuleSolution
|-Controllers
|-Models
|-Views
 |-Preferences
  |-CustomModulePreferenceView.aspx


BaseApplicationSolution
|-Controllers
|-Models
|-Views
 |-Preferences
  |-Preferences.aspx
```

If there is a way to do this, please let me know. Does someone know a solution to get this done using WebForms?

I appreciate your help! Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found another solution to do this in the Blog of Zack Owens which can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zowens/archive/2010/05/26/multi-tenant-asp-net-mvc-introduction.aspx). Thank you for all of your suggestions and ideas!

Answer (score 0):

This sounds a lot like [Portable Areas](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/hex/archive/2009/11/01/asp-net-mvc-portable-areas-via-mvccontrib.aspx) from [MvcContrib](http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Creating%20a%20Portable%20Area). Perhaps you can look at what they've done.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is not supported natively by MVC 2 or 3 as far as I know.

People have come up with some workarounds:

http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/02/14/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc-controller-actions-part-i.aspx

This is a pretty good solution:

http://mvcex.codeplex.com/

Google for "mvc multitenancy" for other examples.